# Child nodes being skipped in certain areas

Tags: xml, vb.net, .net-2.0

I have an xml file I'm reading from to populate a listbox. When I change the selection in a combobox, it searches for the name of that selection in the xml file and shows it's child nodes. But for some reason, there is one entry that never shows it's single child node. I have other nodes that contain just a single child node, and they display fine. Id there something wrong with my code that can be causing this?

```
    Dim xDoc As New XmlDocument
    Dim bldr As New StringBuilder
    Dim crit As String
    Dim val As String

    bldr.Append("//View[@Name='")
    bldr.Append(TextBox2.Text)
    bldr.Append("']")
    crit = bldr.ToString
    xDoc.Load("d:\input\sortedViews.xml")

    Try
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        For Each item As XmlNode In xDoc.SelectSingleNode(crit).ChildNodes
            val = item.InnerText
            ListBox1.Items.Add(val)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        val = Nothing
    End Try
```

Sample nodes: (The first one lists all 3 criteria in listbox, the second one shows nothing)

```
<View Name="vBlueView">
    <Criteria>BlueView Wired</Criteria>
    <Criteria>BlueView Stream</Criteria>
    <Criteria>Blue Star</Criteria>
</View>
<View Name="vBaneWay">
    <Criteria>BaneWay Inc</Criteria>
</View>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML of a node that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: Hmmm--it works for me, but I would remove the Try Catch to see if you are getting an exception for some reason on that node.  The only thing I really did was to add a root `<Views>` element to the xml.  The only other thing I can think of is that you may not be getting "vBaneWay" into the string as you expect...

Comment: When I do that I get a "NullReferenceException was unhandled"

Comment: There you go--do a `msgbox(crit)` before the the For Each statement to make sure it's what you expect.  With the Try block around the whole For Each block, you're going to get nothing if there are any exceptions in any of the loops.

Comment: ...although having invalid criteria doesn't cause any exceptions on my system--I have no theories about what's causing it on yours.

Comment: Yea, it may be that. It's a pretty large file, I think I'll place it in the backlog until Tuesday. Thanks anyway Tony.